# No Registration but no error too

Tags: php, mysql

The Signup page is not registering the details and details are not being saved in table called `members` and also it's showing no error in the signup page post submit

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php'; 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "root";
    $mysql_database = "database";
    $prefix = "";
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $college = $_POST['college'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];

    $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database,$bd) or die("Could not select database");
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user='".$user."'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    echo"<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";

    if($numrows==0) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO members(user, pass, fname, lname, number, gender, college) VALUES('$user', '$pass', '$fname', '$lname', '$number', '$gender', '$college')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        if($result) {
            echo "Success";
        } else {
            echo "Failure!";
        };
    } else {
        echo"<center>This email is already registered , Please login to Continue</center>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: 1) Let's indent your code. 2) Ditch mysql_* 3) stop trying to solve a problem that has been solved hundreds of times - use a standard registration and login app instead of writing another one

Comment: *"its showing no error"* - I don't see any error checking whatsoever. What I also don't see; the html form for this. In short,........ something failed and you need to find out why; check for errors.

Comment: I have used the standard registration page as you can see

Comment: Which *standard*? There's no standard registration page

Comment: you've an answer below; ask them.

Comment: I cannot find error, do you?

Comment: I can come up with a minimum of 5 reasons why your code is failing. Edit: How many can you come up with @HankyPanky

Comment: you could always try to debug on your own [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) -> `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: ^ left out error reporting ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- true, but don't want to overwhelm the OP, as they might feel we are picking on them ;)

Comment: @Sean *Aye, true*. Had they done [what I asked earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404735/no-registration-but-no-error-too#comment70012410_41404735), maybe, just maybe... there'd be new developments. A lot of wasted time if you ask me.

Comment: @Sean oh, and not to mention the time to spend debugging, setting up a db, writing up an answer for this etc.  with the strong possibility of never seeing a green tick..... I think their track record speaks for itself; so I'm out. Voted to close.

Comment: Can you post your error message, Here it is not enough to identify the error

Comment: as I've mentioned there no error message. That is the reason I've posted

Answer (score 0):

> The Signup page is not registering the details and details are not
>   being saved in table called member and also its showing no error in
>   the signup page post submit

The table name is called "member" right ? . And your sql query says "members"

```
$sql="INSERT INTO members(user,pass,fname,lname,number,gender,college) VALUES('$user','$pass','$fname','$lname','$number','$gender','$college')";
```

hence it will not work. But yeah, important things you need to know, Like ec45 said...

> 1.mysql_...() is deprecated. Use PDO instead and if you really love the mysql function, use mysqli...()
>
> 2.Never ever directly use values gotten from a form in an SQL query as it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements .
>
> 3.Please write clean PHP code. Stuff like this is why people abuse PHP . Best regards.

Okay, i tried to quickly write a PDO version of your script . Here it is. Test it and it should work, also check that the correct column names in your databse are represented in your SQL query. Best regards

```
  <?php

    //let's ensure we can see all the errors
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set("display_errors",1);

        include_once "header.php"; 
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database";
            $user="root";
            $password="root";
            //this is PDO . Easier, and better.
            try{
                $db=newPDO($dsn,$user,$password);
                $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo " Couldn't connect to the database because of ".$e;
            }
            //get the values from the form
            $fname = $_POST['fname'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            $user = $_POST['user'];
            $lname = $_POST['lname'];
            $college = $_POST['college'];
            $gender = $_POST['gender'];
            $number = $_POST['number'];

            //function to insert user into the database
            function createUser($fname,$pass,$user,$lname,$college,$gender,$number){

                //first check to ensure its a new user. If its a new user, we carry normal activities else, echo error message
                if(checkUser($email)===false){
                    $sql=" INSERT INTO members(user,pass,fname,lname,number,gender,college) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    $data=array($user,$pass,$fname,$lname,$number,$gender,$college);
                    $db->prepare($sql);
                    $inserted=$db->execute($data);

                    //if it returns true and its inserted, then show a success message
                    $output=(($inserted)?"<section style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'> <h4> You were registered succesfully</h4> </section>":" ");
                    echo $output;
                }else{
                    echo "<section style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'> <h4> Someone's already registered with that name </h4> </section>"
                }
            }

            //helps to check if a user has already been registered
            function checkUser($email){
                //watch the next few lines. Showcases the prepared statements
                $sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE user = ?";
                $data=array($email);
                $db->prepare($sql);
                $prepared=$db->execute($data);
                $result=(($prepared->rowCount() > 0) ? true :false );
                return $result;


            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: thank you for the code but it's still not working yet

Comment: It is showing the same, no error. The signup page reload post submit with no error notifiation

Comment: Perhaps I should see the html code for your form . Use phpmyadmin to check your database if your data gets inserted

Comment: here's the ink of the page which i want to signup. type any vale and submit the form you'll see

Comment: Hmm, from what I noticed, in the form on that page, there are more fields than what is in your initial code. I noticed the email and password fields which are not in your initial code . Also, you should use a select element instead of a text box for gender as people could type in other stuff as gender. Plus, from the code i just tested, you didn't use my code. Try my code

Answer (score 0):

The only answer i can suggest you that instead of using MYSQL just use MYSQLI/ PDO because MYSQL is deprecated.

In your current code if you have error reporting on so you will sure not get error message but MYSQL deprecation warning message will be there.

Comment: This is a comment/suggestion which in so many words has already been addressed in comments.

Comment: So you want us to provide you a full code? This is Question and answer site not a coding provider.